# Solution to Homogeneous Linear Differential Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given is:

$(1-x^2)\dfrac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2} + 2x\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx} - 2y(x) = 0 $

The Solution is:

$y(x) =C_1x + C_2(x^2+1)$

How do I factor the $x$ out in order to get it into a normal "linear" form that contains only coefficients to show that the solution is valid?

Edit: The equation should be both Linear and Homogeneous

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Factor what $x$? What is wrong with the solution as it is? To show the solution is valid, differentiate it and put it in to the original ODE.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this differential equation is to make an Ansatz that the solutions $y=y(x)$ are analytic around $x=0$ and of the form $y(x)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\,a_r\,x^r$.  Then, plugging this assumption into the differential equation, you will find that $a_0=a_2$ and $0=a_3=a_4=\ldots$.  Thus, you have found a $2$-dimensional solution set, which means that these are all solutions as the differential equation is linear of order $2$.

Another way is to notice that $y(x)=x$ is a solution.  Then, we make a different Ansatz, claiming that another solution is of the form $y=xz$ for some function $z=z(x)$.  Plugging this assumption into the differential equation, you will obtain the differential equation
$$x\,\left(1-x^2\right)\,\frac{\text{d}^2z}{\text{d}x^2}+2\,\frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}x}=0\,,$$
which means 
$$\frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}x}=C_2\,\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
for some constant $C_2$.  That is,
$$z(x)=C_1+C_2\,\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
for some constant $C_1$, whence
$$y(x)=C_1\,x+C_2\,\left(x^2+1\right)$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

$(1-x^2)\dfrac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2} + 2x\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx} - 2y(x) = 0 $

Since you know the solution :  $\quad y(x) =C_1x + C_2(x^2+1)\quad$ I suppose that the only question is to show that the solution is valid. If So :

$\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx} =C_1 + 2C_2 x$

$\dfrac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=2C_2$

Puting them into the ODE leads to :

$(1-x^2)\dfrac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2} + 2x\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx} - 2y(x) = (1-x^2)2C_2 + 2x(C_1 + 2C_2 x) - 2 (C_1x + C_2(x^2+1)) = C_1(2x-2x)+C_2(2-2x^2+4x^2-2x^2-2)=0$

Since the simplification leads to $=0$ , the equation is satisfied and the solution is valid.